# Elements taking over the space of an element with position absolute

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am trying to have a div at the top of my page that fits with no space against the top and sides.

All the example I have seen on how to do this put the div position to absolute.

But when I do this, the following img sibling moves to the top of the page with the previous div.

So I have two questions. Why does the following sibling move? Also, how can I have a div fit with 0 space against the top, without having position:absolute

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: #888888;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#000000">

  <div>
    <h1>HEADER</h1>
  </div>

  <img src="pic_mountain.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You take elements out of the normal document flow when you position them `absolute`, so any element following an absolute positioned element will occupy the space left by it. You'll need to compensate for this space somehow, usually by adding a buffer of space, like using a margin, so that the absolute element doesn't sit on top of any other element still in the document flow. So in your use-case here, you'll probably want to add `margin-top: 100px` to your `img` element.

Comment: Why do you use absolute ? is it for the *spacing trouble* you have or is it because you want to stick the header at the top of the window and let scroll only the content ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `position: absolute` to align things to top just use `margin: 0` on the `body, h1` Like:

```
body, h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
body, h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  background: #888888;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body bgcolor="#000000">

<div>
    <h1>HEADER</h1>
</div>

<img src="http://placehold.it/304x228" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">

</body>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

When you give an element `position: absolute`, you remove it from the normal flow of the document. This means that it no longer takes up any space in the layout. As a result, surrounding elements don't know it exists and take over the previously used space.

You don't need absolute positioning in this case. The reason for the gaps are default margins on elements set by the browser. Just override those defaults with your own settings.

```css
body, h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 100px;
  background: #888888;
}
```

```html
<body  bgcolor="#000000"bgcolsor="#000000">

  <div>
    <h1>HEADER</h1>
  </div>

  <img src="pic_mountain.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">

</body>
```

More information:

- [Normal flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Visual_formatting_model#Normal_flow) ~ MDN
- [Absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning) ~ MDN

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the following sibling move?

It moves to the top because the first `div` is `position: absolute`, that's what expected when we apply this property / value. This `div` is also `relative` to the parent / body and the whole document (because no `position: relative` was specified anywhere else). When you apply `position: absolute` you remove that element from the normal document flow. It kind of **flies over** the document.

When you have this option applied to an element nested to something using `position: relative`, you'll see that the child will obey the parent's `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom`.

> Also, how can I have a div fit with 0 space against the top, without having position:absolute

This way:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

With:

```
h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Or:

```
div {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Without** `position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%;` on the `div`. `div`'s default params will take over what's needed.

The `margin-top: 0` or `overflow: hidden` must be there just to get rid of the top `h1`'s default margin, because when there's a margin in a case like that, the `div` `background` won't follow the whole `div` flow. Using `overflow: hidden` the way I've shown you is a technique of "clearing" things, like clearfix and others. You can read more about them [here](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/).

Also, [Michael_B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3597276/michael-b) links about [normal flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Visual_formatting_model#Normal_flow) and [absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning) are very relevant and a must read.